# Unable to Store Data in MySql Database using Laravel and React

Tags: laravel

I am a Node.js Dev and I am having a hard time with Laravel, I am following a Tutorial but when i try to store my data it gives me this Error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

My Table Name is: `_donor_sign_up`.  I assume that something is wrong with controller code.

Here is The React Code:

```
const PostData =async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Posting");
        const res = await axios.post('/signups', user);
        console.log(res);
        
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // return response()->json("Hello World");
        $newSignup = _donor_sign_up::create([
            'fname' => $request->fname,
            'lname' => $request->lname,
            'email' =>$request->email,
            'password' =>$request->password,
            're'=>$request->re,
            'role'=>$request->role
        ]);

        if($newSignup)
        {
            return response()->json("Hello World");
        }
        
    }
```

Web.php code:

```
Route::post("/signups", "App\Http\Controllers\signupController@store");
```

Model code:

```
class _donor_sign_up extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["fname", "lname", "email","password","re","role"];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... check the error logs to see why its throwing a 500 error ... also is there any reason you named your model in such an odd manner? and why the table is named that way (starting with an underscore)?

Comment: I've checked the error and its showing me this error:
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Comment: right, and what table does it say it is looking for?

Comment: I've used _ because my teacher told us that table name should start with underscore

Comment: its looking for 'laravel_db._donor_sign_ups' table

Comment: first time I have ever heard someone say that ... unless you tell the model what your table is called it will use the class name in a plural form as the table name (as convention is for the table to be in the plural form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will have to define the table name for this model I would name the model in a more conventional way as `DonorSignUp` then you can define the table name property on the Model so it knows what the table is named (since your table name does not follow convention; not plural):

```
protected $table = '_donor_sign_up';
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Eloquent Model Conventions - Table Names](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names)

If you were following conventions the model would be `DonorSignUp` and the table would be named `donor_sign_ups`.